# How to fix error upgrading Wagtail 2.10.2 to 2.11.8?

Tags: django, wagtail

I've been upgrading from Wagtail v1.13 / Django v1.11 / Python 3.5.2 to bring a project up to date.

Everything has gone smoothly I'm now at Wagtail 2.10.2 / Django 3.0.14 / Python 3.8.9

The project uses puput, so can't go beyond Django 3.0.14 until puput supports a newer version of Django.  That's not a problem, I'm happy with that for now.

However after installing Wagtail 2.11.8, when I run makemigrations I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'wagtail.core.models' has no attribute 'MultiTableCopyMixin'
```

The Wagtail 2.10.2/Django 3.0.14 combination created 0038_auto_20210624_0634.py that contains the following line:

```
bases=(wagtail.core.models.MultiTableCopyMixin, models.Model),
```

Sure enough in Wagtail 2.10.2 wagtail.core.models.MultiTableCopyMixin exists, but in Wagtail 2.11.* MultiTableCopyMixin has been removed.

I've also tried keeping Django at version 2.2.24, and still get the same problem.

Any ideas?

Full contents of the auto-generated migration below, see the 2nd entry on the operations array:

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.24 on 2021-06-24 14:07

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
import modelcluster.fields
import wagtail.core.models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('contenttypes', '0002_remove_content_type_name'),
        ('auth', '0011_update_proxy_permissions'),
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('wagtailcore', '0037_auto_20210624_0316'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Task',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='name')),
                ('active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Active tasks can be added to workflows. Deactivating a task does not remove it from existing workflows.', verbose_name='active')),
                ('content_type', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='wagtail_tasks', to='contenttypes.ContentType', verbose_name='content type')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'task',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'tasks',
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='TaskState',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('status', models.CharField(choices=[('in_progress', 'In progress'), ('approved', 'Approved'), ('rejected', 'Rejected'), ('skipped', 'Skipped'), ('cancelled', 'Cancelled')], default='in_progress', max_length=50, verbose_name='status')),
                ('started_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='started at')),
                ('finished_at', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='finished at')),
                ('comment', models.TextField(blank=True)),
                ('content_type', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='wagtail_task_states', to='contenttypes.ContentType', verbose_name='content type')),
                ('finished_by', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='finished_task_states', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='finished by')),
                ('page_revision', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='task_states', to='wagtailcore.PageRevision', verbose_name='page revision')),
                ('task', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='task_states', to='wagtailcore.Task', verbose_name='task')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'Task state',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'Task states',
            },
            bases=(wagtail.core.models.MultiTableCopyMixin, models.Model),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Workflow',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='name')),
                ('active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Active workflows can be added to pages. Deactivating a workflow does not remove it from existing pages.', verbose_name='active')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'workflow',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'workflows',
            },
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='site',
            name='site_name',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, default='Default', help_text='Human-readable name for the site.', max_length=255, verbose_name='site name'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='GroupApprovalTask',
            fields=[
                ('task_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='wagtailcore.Task')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'Group approval task',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'Group approval tasks',
            },
            bases=('wagtailcore.task',),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='WorkflowState',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('status', models.CharField(choices=[('in_progress', 'In progress'), ('approved', 'Approved'), ('needs_changes', 'Needs changes'), ('cancelled', 'Cancelled')], default='in_progress', max_length=50, verbose_name='status')),
                ('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='created at')),
                ('current_task_state', models.OneToOneField(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, to='wagtailcore.TaskState', verbose_name='current task state')),
                ('page', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='workflow_states', to='wagtailcore.Page', verbose_name='page')),
                ('requested_by', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='requested_workflows', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='requested by')),
                ('workflow', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='workflow_states', to='wagtailcore.Workflow', verbose_name='workflow')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'Workflow state',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'Workflow states',
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='WorkflowPage',
            fields=[
                ('page', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='wagtailcore.Page', verbose_name='page')),
                ('workflow', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='workflow_pages', to='wagtailcore.Workflow', verbose_name='workflow')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'workflow page',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'workflow pages',
            },
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='taskstate',
            name='workflow_state',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='task_states', to='wagtailcore.WorkflowState', verbose_name='workflow state'),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='PageLogEntry',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('label', models.TextField()),
                ('action', models.CharField(blank=True, db_index=True, max_length=255)),
                ('data_json', models.TextField(blank=True)),
                ('timestamp', models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='timestamp (UTC)')),
                ('content_changed', models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=False)),
                ('deleted', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('content_type', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='+', to='contenttypes.ContentType', verbose_name='content type')),
                ('page', models.ForeignKey(db_constraint=False, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+', to='wagtailcore.Page')),
                ('revision', models.ForeignKey(db_constraint=False, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+', to='wagtailcore.PageRevision')),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(db_constraint=False, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'page log entry',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'page log entries',
                'ordering': ['-timestamp', '-id'],
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='WorkflowTask',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('sort_order', models.IntegerField(blank=True, editable=False, null=True)),
                ('task', models.ForeignKey(limit_choices_to={'active': True}, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='workflow_tasks', to='wagtailcore.Task', verbose_name='task')),
                ('workflow', modelcluster.fields.ParentalKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='workflow_tasks', to='wagtailcore.Workflow', verbose_name='workflow_tasks')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'workflow task order',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'workflow task orders',
                'ordering': ['sort_order'],
                'abstract': False,
                'unique_together': {('workflow', 'task')},
            },
        ),
        migrations.AddConstraint(
            model_name='workflowstate',
            constraint=models.UniqueConstraint(condition=models.Q(('status', 'in_progress'), ('status', 'needs_changes'), _connector='OR'), fields=('page',), name='unique_in_progress_workflow'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='groupapprovaltask',
            name='groups',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(help_text='Pages at this step in a workflow will be moderated or approved by these groups of users', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups'),
        ),
    ]
```

The output of showmigrations is as follows, run on Wagtail 2.10.2, trying to run on 2.11.8 throws same error as before:

```
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
home
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_contentpage
 [X] 0003_auto_20170427_1205
 [X] 0004_auto_20170427_1210
 [X] 0005_auto_20170427_1214
 [X] 0006_auto_20170427_1215
 [X] 0007_auto_20170427_1216
 [X] 0008_auto_20170430_0530
 [X] 0009_auto_20170430_0551
 [X] 0010_auto_20170430_0639
 [X] 0011_auto_20170430_0642
 [X] 0012_auto_20170501_1035
 [X] 0013_auto_20170501_1046
 [X] 0014_auto_20170501_1055
 [X] 0015_auto_20170501_1101
 [X] 0016_auto_20170501_1103
 [X] 0017_auto_20170501_1106
 [X] 0018_auto_20170501_2305
 [X] 0019_auto_20170501_2325
 [X] 0020_auto_20170501_2350
 [X] 0021_auto_20170501_2354
 [X] 0022_auto_20170502_0000
 [X] 0023_auto_20170502_0012
 [X] 0024_auto_20170502_0030
 [X] 0025_auto_20170502_0054
 [X] 0026_auto_20170502_0237
 [X] 0027_auto_20170502_0524
 [X] 0028_auto_20170502_0853
 [X] 0029_auto_20170502_0856
 [X] 0030_auto_20170511_0012
 [X] 0031_auto_20170511_0017
 [X] 0032_auto_20170511_0021
 [X] 0033_auto_20170511_0023
 [X] 0034_auto_20170511_0025
 [X] 0035_auto_20170511_0027
 [X] 0036_auto_20170511_0030
 [X] 0037_auto_20170511_0032
 [X] 0038_auto_20170511_0034
 [X] 0039_auto_20170511_0035
 [X] 0040_auto_20170511_0037
 [X] 0041_auto_20170511_0039
 [X] 0042_auto_20170511_0045
 [X] 0043_auto_20170511_0048
 [X] 0044_auto_20170511_0054
 [X] 0045_auto_20170511_0056
 [X] 0046_auto_20170511_0105
 [X] 0047_auto_20170511_0106
 [X] 0048_auto_20170511_0111
 [X] 0049_auto_20170511_0113
 [X] 0050_auto_20170511_0114
 [X] 0051_auto_20170513_0708
 [X] 0052_auto_20170513_0709
 [X] 0053_auto_20170515_2351
 [X] 0054_auto_20170516_0021
 [X] 0055_auto_20170516_0344
 [X] 0056_contactpage
 [X] 0057_auto_20170719_1137
 [X] 0058_auto_20170824_0004
 [X] 0059_auto_20170824_0014
 [X] 0060_auto_20171016_0146
 [X] 0061_auto_20171120_0657
 [X] 0062_auto_20171120_0709
 [X] 0063_auto_20171120_0711
 [X] 0064_auto_20171120_0719
 [X] 0065_auto_20171120_0720
 [X] 0066_auto_20171120_0725
 [X] 0067_auto_20171126_0205
 [X] 0068_auto_20171127_2239
 [X] 0069_auto_20171207_0317
 [X] 0070_auto_20180122_0204
 [X] 0071_auto_20180204_2258
 [X] 0072_auto_20180204_2306
 [X] 0073_donatepage
 [X] 0074_contact2page
 [X] 0075_auto_20180705_0128
 [X] 0076_auto_20190926_1406
 [X] 0077_auto_20190926_1557
 [X] 0078_auto_20191001_0448
 [X] 0079_auto_20191003_1227
 [X] 0080_auto_20200211_1115
 [X] 0081_auto_20210217_1427
 [X] 0082_contentholdercategory_contentholderdetailpage_contentholderlistingpage
 [X] 0083_contentholderdetailpage_show_categories
 [X] 0084_auto_20210310_0455
 [X] 0085_contentholderlistingpage_body2
 [X] 0086_flexiblecontactpage
 [X] 0087_auto_20210501_0155
 [X] 0088_auto_20210503_1053
 [X] 0089_auto_20210503_1123
 [X] 0090_auto_20210511_1644
 [X] 0091_auto_20210511_1656
 [X] 0092_auto_20210519_1637
 [X] 0093_auto_20210525_0709
 [X] 0094_footersettings
 [X] 0095_auto_20210607_1158
 [X] 0096_auto_20210623_0242
leads
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20170524_0535
 [X] 0003_auto_20170525_0041
 [X] 0004_auto_20170525_0131
 [X] 0005_auto_20170525_0142
 [X] 0006_auto_20170525_0326
 [X] 0007_leaddb_referer
 [X] 0008_auto_20170525_0851
 [X] 0009_auto_20170526_0230
 [X] 0010_auto_20170526_0232
 [X] 0011_auto_20170526_0313
 [X] 0012_auto_20170526_0321
 [X] 0013_auto_20170526_0324
 [X] 0014_auto_20180322_0049
 [X] 0015_auto_20180713_0351
 [X] 0016_auto_20180713_0357
 [X] 0017_auto_20180713_0708
 [X] 0018_auto_20180713_0715
 [X] 0019_auto_20180713_0754
 [X] 0020_auto_20180713_0803
 [X] 0021_auto_20180713_0804
 [X] 0022_leaddb_other
 [X] 0023_auto_20180720_0341
 [X] 0024_auto_20180724_0224
 [X] 0025_auto_20190717_1540
 [X] 0026_auto_20190717_1616
 [X] 0027_auto_20190717_1618
 [X] 0028_auto_20190718_1533
 [X] 0029_auto_20190721_1146
 [X] 0030_auto_20190924_1501
 [X] 0031_auto_20210217_1427
 [X] 0032_flexibleleaddb
 [X] 0033_auto_20210519_1637
 [X] 0034_auto_20210621_1407
 [X] 0035_auto_20210621_1534
postgres_search
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_add_autocomplete
 [X] 0003_title
puput
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_blogpage_short_feed_description
 [X] 0003_remove_blogpage_short_feed_description
 [X] 0004_blogpage_short_feed_description
 [X] 0005_auto_20210620_1525
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
sites
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_domain_unique
taggit
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20150616_2121
 [X] 0003_taggeditem_add_unique_index
wagtailadmin
 [X] 0001_create_admin_access_permissions
wagtailcore
 [X] 0001_squashed_0016_change_page_url_path_to_text_field (16 squashed migrations)
 [X] 0017_change_edit_page_permission_description
 [X] 0018_pagerevision_submitted_for_moderation_index
 [X] 0019_verbose_names_cleanup
 [X] 0020_add_index_on_page_first_published_at
 [X] 0021_capitalizeverbose
 [X] 0022_add_site_name
 [X] 0023_alter_page_revision_on_delete_behaviour
 [X] 0024_collection
 [X] 0025_collection_initial_data
 [X] 0026_group_collection_permission
 [X] 0027_fix_collection_path_collation
 [X] 0024_alter_page_content_type_on_delete_behaviour
 [X] 0028_merge
 [X] 0029_unicode_slugfield_dj19
 [X] 0030_index_on_pagerevision_created_at
 [X] 0031_add_page_view_restriction_types
 [X] 0032_add_bulk_delete_page_permission
 [X] 0033_auto_20170401_0651
 [X] 0034_auto_20170510_0533
 [X] 0035_auto_20170822_1810
 [X] 0036_auto_20210624_0046
 [X] 0037_auto_20210624_0316
 [X] 0038_auto_20210624_0634
wagtaildocs
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_initial_data
 [X] 0003_add_verbose_names
 [X] 0004_capitalizeverbose
 [X] 0005_document_collection
 [X] 0006_copy_document_permissions_to_collections
 [X] 0005_alter_uploaded_by_user_on_delete_action
 [X] 0007_merge
 [X] 0008_document_file_size
 [X] 0009_document_verbose_name_plural
 [X] 0010_document_file_hash
wagtailembeds
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_add_verbose_names
 [X] 0003_capitalizeverbose
 [X] 0004_embed_verbose_name_plural
 [X] 0005_specify_thumbnail_url_max_length
wagtailforms
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_add_verbose_names
 [X] 0003_capitalizeverbose
 [X] 0004_add_verbose_name_plural
wagtailimages
 [X] 0001_squashed_0021 (21 squashed migrations)
 [X] 0022_uploadedimage
wagtailmenus
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20160129_0901
 [X] 0003_auto_20160129_2339
 [X] 0004_auto_20160130_0024
 [X] 0005_auto_20160130_2209
 [X] 0006_auto_20160131_1347
 [X] 0007_auto_20160131_2000
 [X] 0008_auto_20160131_2327
 [X] 0009_auto_20160201_0859
 [X] 0010_auto_20160201_1558
 [X] 0011_auto_20160415_1519
 [X] 0012_auto_20160419_0039
 [X] 0013_auto_20160423_1124
 [X] 0014_auto_20160423_1339
 [X] 0015_auto_20160423_1348
 [X] 0016_auto_20160930_0645
 [X] 0017_auto_20161013_1658
 [X] 0018_auto_20161204_2043
 [X] 0019_auto_20161204_2143
 [X] 0020_auto_20161210_0004
 [X] 0021_auto_20170106_2352
 [X] 0022_auto_20170913_2125
 [X] 0023_remove_use_specific
wagtailmetadata
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20160607_2150
 [X] 0003_auto_20160909_1000
 [X] 0004_remove_sitemetadatapreferences
 [X] 0005_metadatasettings
 [X] 0006_drop_metadatasettings
wagtailredirects
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_add_verbose_names
 [X] 0003_make_site_field_editable
 [X] 0004_set_unique_on_path_and_site
 [X] 0005_capitalizeverbose
 [X] 0006_redirect_increase_max_length
wagtailsearch
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_add_verbose_names
 [X] 0003_remove_editors_pick
 [X] 0004_querydailyhits_verbose_name_plural
wagtailusers
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_add_verbose_name_on_userprofile
 [X] 0003_add_verbose_names
 [X] 0004_capitalizeverbose
 [X] 0005_make_related_name_wagtail_specific
 [X] 0006_userprofile_prefered_language
 [X] 0007_userprofile_current_time_zone
 [X] 0008_userprofile_avatar
 [X] 0009_userprofile_verbose_name_plural
```

After seeing that the latest version of wagtail doesn't have the 'bases' line, I have discovered that if I comment out the bases line in the wagtailcore_migrations added to my project, the error goes away.

But I then get asked:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'locale' to page without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

When I select 1, I get:

```
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now
```

I've tried entering 'en-us', and timezone.now.  But I always get an error when running migrate:

```
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got...
```

Followed by either

- 'en-us' when I enter 'en-us'
- datetime.datetime when I enter timezone.now

What do I put here?

I think it's not creating the Locale database tables.

I've noticed it's creating files in home/wagtailcore_migrations which mostly copy the files in site-packages/wagtail/core/migrations. How can this happen?

Comment: Can you share the full `0038_auto_20210624_0634.py` (or at least enough of the context to see what class/model the `bases` option is defined on)?

Comment: Added the full 0038_auto_20210624_0634.py as requested.

Comment: Ah - this is a migration being created inside wagtailcore? That shouldn't happen - wagtailcore should never have migrations other than the ones included in the Wagtail package itself, otherwise you'll run into consistency issues with the migration history. I suspect this is a Puput bug...

Comment: Yes, auto generated from inside wagtail core.  I've checked, it's coming from the wagtail distribution in /wagtail/core/migrations/0047_add_workflow_models.py.

Comment: I'm not sure how you've ended up with an auto-generated migration that duplicates [the same table creations as Wagtail's own migrations](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/main/wagtail/core/migrations/0047_add_workflow_models.py), unless you've previously hacked around with that migration folder to resolve earlier migration conflicts - in which case the problems could go back a lot further and this could get very tricky to untangle. Could you share the output of running `./manage.py showmigrations`?

Comment: I note the version of 0038_auto_20210624_0634.py you reference doesn't contain the "bases=" lines.  Every time I've done an upgrade I've run makemigrations and migrate, this is how I've ended up with this file nameed 0038_auto_20210624_0634.py in wagtailcore_migrations.

Comment: I've added the output of showmigrations as requested.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this problem dates back to 2017, when your project was on Wagtail 1.9, and something in your project - most likely [this Puput bug](https://github.com/APSL/puput/issues/107) - generated the spurious `0033_auto_20170401_0651` migration inside wagtailcore.

For some reason, the presence of this migration prevented Django from seeing the subsequent migrations inside wagtailcore that were supplied in later Wagtail releases. (This is not what I'd expect to happen: I'd expect it to notice the presence of multiple migration `0033`s that don't have a shared history, and fail with a migration conflict.) Instead, running `./manage.py makemigrations` caused additional migrations to be auto-generated, replicating the schema changes that would normally be handled by Wagtail's supplied migrations. This is a bad thing for a couple of reasons:

- Wagtail's own migrations include some data migrations which the auto-generated ones won't replicate. (For example, Wagtail 1.12 introduced a 'draft title' field, and populated this from the main title field; since this latter step was missed in your version, you're likely to end up with pages with blank titles appearing in the admin.)
- If you ever install your project in a new environment and perform a fresh installation of the Wagtail package at that point, your existing codebase and database will contain references to autogenerated migrations that don't exist in that environment, which will result in consistency errors on `./manage.py migrate`.

Since this is a deep-rooted problem going back many years, that may have had knock-on effects on your project that aren't apparent here, I can't promise 100% reliable steps to fix this, but the following should get you on the right track. I'd recommend taking a backup of your database and saving a copy of the autogenerated wagtailcore migrations (somewhere outside of your codebase where they won't interfere), and if possible, start these steps from a version of your codebase/database running under Wagtail 1.13, from before you started the current upgrade. (As mentioned above, the problem began even before that point, but this way your migrations will not have gone as far down the 'wrong path'.)

- Search your project codebase for any migrations within your own apps that refer to the autogenerated migrations `0033_auto_20170401_0651`, `0034_auto_20170510_0533`, `0035_auto_20170822_1810`, `0036_auto_20210624_0046`, `0037_auto_20210624_0316`, `0038_auto_20210624_0634` - for example:

  ```
  dependencies = [
      ('home', '0123_some_other_migration'),
      ('wagtailcore', '0034_auto_20170510_0533'),  # <- change this line
  ]
  ```

  Change these to `'0032_add_bulk_delete_page_permission'` - this way, you're specifying that these migrations should run after the last 'real' migration from Wagtail 1.9, but do not depend on the autogenerated ones, making it possible to roll back the autogenerated migration without reverting your own project migrations and potentially losing data.
- Run `./manage.py migrate wagtailcore 0032` - this should hopefully show the autogenerated wagtailcore migrations being rolled back, and nothing else.
- Uninstall the Wagtail package with `pip uninstall wagtail`, then reinstall the same version that you had - this should remove the autogenerated migrations. Check the output from `pip` carefully - it might stop with a prompt telling you that the autogenerated migration files will be left behind, and if so, quit, delete those files manually, and retry the uninstall command.
- Run `./manage.py migrate` - hopefully this should now apply the real migrations from wagtailcore, and no autogenerated ones.
- Run through the Wagtail upgrade sequence as before, upgrading one version at a time and running `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate` after each one. If everything has worked correctly, `makemigrations` should not create any migrations within wagtailcore (or any other of Wagtail's own apps) at any point.